# Is there any aspect of computer forensics that is off-topic for IT Security?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

There is a proposed Stack Exchange site about [Computer Forensics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9121/computer-forensics). Are there any questions there that would not be on-topic on [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?

I'd say no, but I'd prefer to have confirmation (or infirmation) from a pro.

(Also raised [on the Area 51 discussion zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/is-there-any-aspect-of-computer-forensics-that-is-off-topic-for-it-security).)

Comment: Good call @Gilles - it is entirely within our scope. So I've upvoted your discussion point and added my support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completed - proposal closed by @Shog9

Answer (score 4):

Good to see that this has already been handled, but FTR:

The only things I can think of that might be out of IT Security's realm here, would be some particular "how do I use" or other "application troubleshooting" questions which more appropriately belong on SU/SF.  There's also the usually off-topic "shopping recommendation" types and such, which would just be closed no matter where they are in SE.

So, unless anyone else can think of a subset of Computer Forensics questions which fits the SE model, is off-topic on any other current SE site, *and* is large enough to be worth making its *own* site, I agree with the proposal closure.